# How to *not* save local variables in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model that uses TensorFlow's AUC operation. This creates a few local variables (true positives, true negatives, etc.). Despite trying to save only **global** variables in this model, I still get local ones when I load the model. This is an issue because after restoring them, they are Tensors and not Variables anymore. Thus attempting to initialize local variables gives me errors.

How can I save a model in TensorFlow without any local variables?

Here's some code to reproduce my issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.random_normal([10, 1])
labels = tf.cast(tf.round(tf.random_uniform([10, 1])), tf.int32)
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 1)
predictions = tf.sigmoid(logits)
auc_val, auc_op = tf.metrics.auc(labels, predictions)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer()]) # or else tf complains when saving
print(tf.local_variables()) # shows 4 local *variables*
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.global_variables()) # trying to save only globals
saver.save(sess, 'test.save')

tf.reset_default_graph() # clear old graph
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('test.save.meta')
saver.restore(sess, 'test.save')
print(tf.local_variables()) # contains 4 *tensors*
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) # throws an AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'
```